# MySQL Error 1064 when updating multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-update, multiple-columns

I have following SQL Query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = '2', dec = '268435458001932988' WHERE id = 29952
```

table is:

```
status = varchar(1)
dec = varchar(23)
```

After what i read in manual i can update multiple columns by seperating them with ",".

So why i get a syntax error (1064) here?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dec = '268435458001932988' WHERE id = 29952' at line 1
```

Comment: Is there an `id` column?

Comment: yes, when i remove ", dec = '268435458001932988'" it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEC` is a reserved word in MySQL apparently.  Use backticks.

```
UPDATE Mytable SET status = '2', `dec` = 'etc.'...
```

List of reserved words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: argh... (headbang)... thanks... working now... they should really update their error messages :D

Comment: @MichaelGrenzer I can't say I don't disagree ... MySQL is pretty notorious for ambiguous error messages

Comment: and this took me 3 hours of headache.. lol. i should send them an invoice for aspirin... will accept in a few mins.. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`dec` is a reserved word (shorthand for `decimal`). Try quoting the `dec` identifier with backticks:

update mytable set status = '2', `dec` = '268435458001932988' where id = 29952;

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 UPDATE mytable SET status = '2', `dec` = '268435458001932988' WHERE id = 29952
```

`DEC` is reserved keyword for mysql.